# Hiding all but first table row with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a table with a drop-down html selector in the first row. The first option is blank.

I need to hide all rows in the table except the ones that match selector value. If the first option is selected -- hide all rows below. The reason i used class for TRs, because there could be multiple rows for some matched options.

**JS**

```
$("#mySelector").change(function(){
    opt = $(this).val();
    if(opt != "") {
        $("." + opt).show();
    } else {
        $("#myTbl tr:not(first-child)").hide(); 
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="myTbl">
<tr>
   <td>
    <select id="mySelector">
    <option> select one
    <option value="val1"> v1
    <option value="val2"> v12
    <option value="val3"> v3
    </selector>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr class="val1">
   <td>
    asdasd 1
   </td>
</tr>

<tr class="val2">
   <td>
    asdasd 2
   </td>
</tr>

<tr class="val3">
   <td>
    asdasd 3
   </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

It seems like it should work, but it doesn't. What am I missing?

Comment: There are lot of ways to filter.. You can also try `$("#myTbl tr:gt(0)").hide();` (Nothing different from others though)

Comment: I prefer the `:gt(0)` because it require's less code and is easier to read.

Comment: @KevinB then I shall reveal my deleted answer ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You missed the `:` before `first-child`

```
$("#myTbl tr:not(:first-child)").hide();
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$("#myTbl tr:not(:first)");`?

Comment: first-child should work too (haven't tested) in this case since it would be the first child of the containing tbody or table.

Comment: Of course you could also go the route of `$("#myTbl tr").first().nextAll().hide();` Would do same thing :P
---
I <3 jQuery!

Comment: @Vega `:not` acts as a filter, meaning it filters the current selection based on the passed in selector. http://jsfiddle.net/ducYE/1/

Comment: @SpYk3HH I would expect your method to be faster

Comment: @KevinB Yea, seems like that but confusing though when you compare `$("#myTbl tr:not(:first)");` and `$("#myTbl tr:not(:first-child)");` returning same results. Thanks for the DEMO. :)

Comment: @KevinB. Yep, so do I, not so sure if it faster than `:gt(0)`, maybe.

Comment: What if it's not the first child or any child with class?

Comment: @Si8 then it would be a different question/answer.

Comment: I was able to figure it out from some google search... thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#myTbl tr:not(:eq(0))").hide();
```

Or:

```
$("#myTbl tr:not(:first)").hide();
```

You need to add a value attribute to the first `<option>`:

```
<select id="mySelector">
<option value=""> select one // <<<<======
<option value="val1"> v1
<option value="val2"> v12
<option value="val3"> v3
</select> // Not </selector>
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/qyTpf/)

---

Note that `opt = $(this).val();`
should be `this.value`  nice, clear, clean and faster.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like below,

```
$("#mySelector").change(function(){
    var opt = $(this).val();
    if(opt != "") {
        $("." + opt).show();
    } else {
        $("#myTbl tr:gt(0)").hide(); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#tableBody tr:gt(0)').hide();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.